# ASP.NET MVC Don't add data to table if it is null or 0 from excel file

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, excel, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an excel file that has the ff. data:

**ordNo** - **ordDate**

9 - 2013-10-22

10 - null

11 - 0

12 - 2013-10-23

13 - 2013-10-24

I also have this code below and it also add those who have NULL or 0 ordDate in the orderTable:

```
using (var trans = DB.db.GetTransaction())
                                    {
                                        ordNo = Convert.ToInt32(DB.db.Insert("dbo.orderTable", "ordNo", new
                                                                                                                {
                                                                                                                    ordNo = data.ordNo,
                                                                                                                    ordDate = data.ordDate,
                                                                                                                }));

                                        trans.Complete();
                                    }
```

I want to add the ordNo and ordDate in the orderTable but only those who have dates.

How can I do that by uploading an excel file and with the use of asp.net mvc?

I badly need your help guys. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using (var trans = DB.db.GetTransaction())
{
    if(data.ordDate!=null)
    {
        ordNo = Convert.ToInt32(DB.db.Insert("dbo.orderTable", "ordNo", new {ordNo =data.ordNo,ordDate = data.ordDate,}));
    }
    trans.Complete();
}
```

If you have string data type as `ordDate`, you can add additional condition to check `0` as well

```
    if(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(data.ordDate) 
                   && data.ordDate.Trim() !="0")
    {


    }
```

Comment: Hi @Damith the first method works! I haven't tried the second but thank you so much for helping me :)